# logback: Correct file name pattern for weekly rolling

Tags: java, logback

I've tried the following rollingPolicy, but the log file didn't roll:

```
    <rollingPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>log-%d{yyyy-ww}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>26</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
```

The `fileNamePattern` correspondes to the file definition of the appender.

Is my file name pattern wrong?

Comment: How much time did you run it? Are log entries being generated?

Comment: @aled Yes, the log entries are generated correctly, and the service is running more than 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me! As so often, the problem often lies between the ears.
In my project, I moved the log files to another directory. I changed the file tag of the appender but not the fileNamePattern of the rolling policy.

To avoid such mistakes, I suggest to work consistently with variables! Example:

```
<property name="log_path" value="/var/log/app-name"/>
<property name="log_name" value="myLog"/>
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <property name="app_log" value="${log_path}/${log_name}"/>
    <file>${app_log}.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d [%t] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${app_log}.%d{yyyy-MM}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>12</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```